# Changing the width of an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, twitter

I am having such a difficult trying to change the width of a twitter timeline iframe. I have looked through the developer tools inspect an element and changed the width on multiple elements, but nothing seems to be working.

I have tried changing:

```
.SandboxRoot, env-wide {
    width: 30%;
}
.timeline-Widget {
    width: 30%;
}
.twitter-timeline, .twitter-timeline-rendered {

    width: 30%;
}

#twitter-widget-0 {

    width: 30%;
}
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9pnxL6fb/. If you need to see it live to inspect, just let me know.

Why can I not change the width based on the elements I am using?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9pnxL6fb/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to target the iframe inside the #blue div

```
#blue iframe {width:30%!important;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use !important . I hope it will help.

```
#blue {
   width: 30% !important;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="blue">
<div class="twitter-iframe">
<a class="twitter-timeline"
</div>
</div>
```

CSS Code

```
#blue  {
    width: 100%;
}

.twitter-iframe {
    width: 30%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the dimensions are hardcoded by default as served by Twitter, you won't be able to override it with just CSS. Instead, override by changing the attributes supplied in your js. 
[Twitter widget documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/web/embedded-timelines/parameters)

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways you can get this to work is by using jQuery with some changes to the CSS as follows: The other answers are semi correct, you can override with code below, just changing the css might not work in a different environment.

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    $('iframe[id^=twitter-widget-]').each(function () {
        var head = $(this).contents().find('head');
        if (head.length) {
            head.append('<style>.timeline { max-width: 100% !important; width: 100% !important; } .timeline .stream { max-width: none !important; width: 100% !important; }</style>');
    }
        $('#twitter-widget-0').append($('<div class=timeline>'));
    })
});
```

CSS:

```
iframe[id^='twitter-widget-0'] {
height:600px !important;
margin-bottom:10px !important;
width:100% !important;
}
```

Working fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/48dy23ep/1/

Comment: I don't see anything different in your fiddle then what I had?

Comment: What other kind of environment are you referring to? I am trying to change this in a media query and that's all.

Comment: in some cases, depending on how you load your css it might not automatically override twitter's css always, but with this it waits to load the iframe and then changes the css on the page

Answer (score 0):

It is rather a hacking than a web mastering :-)

Normally there is no possibility to manipulate iframe content from a parent document. This is protected due to security reasons, to not inject any suspicious JavaScript code etc. I was looking at you code generating the post. The code requests a twitter API to get the complete post generation JavaScript file and puts it into your DOM.

The only way would be the Twitter post API, but it is limited... ([Twitter Widget Javascript](https://dev.twitter.com/web/javascript))